# Adding number and array produces weird result in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome

When working in the console of developer tools in chrome, I types in,
`2 + []`
and it produced the unexpected result `"2"`. The same happens with every number. What is happening? Also, when we add some number to a nonempty array, it concatenates the number and the first element of that list, e.g., `2+["abc",6]` produces "2abc, 6".
Note: I don't have much experience in js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to coercion in javascript.

both `2` and `[]` are tried to get converted to a common type - `string`.

Now, `toString` method of array returns `""` and `toString` of Number returns "2" in this case.

Therefore to get the result - `"2"` after `""` and "2" are concatenated.

Answer (score 1):

From What I observe, Javascript does implicit type conversions and if both sides of the operand are different, JS will try to typecast them to string in case of `+` operation.

For example, if you try `[12,34].toString()` it will return `"12,34"` and and if you do `2+[]` js will interpret it as `2.toString() + [].toString()` thus the output `"2"`.

You can try different combinations in your browser console for more experiments.